# Spring Batch CompositeItemProcessor get value from other delegates

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a compositeItemProcessor as below

```
<bean id="compositeItemProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.example.itemProcessor1"/>
                <bean class="com.example.itemProcessor2"/>
                <bean class="com.example.itemProcessor3"/>
                <bean class="com.example.itemProcessor4"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The issue i have is that within itemProcessor4 i require values from both itemProcessor1 and itemProcessor3.

I have looked at using the Step Execution Context but this does not work as this is within one step. I have also looked at using @AfterProcess within ItemProcessor1 but this does not work as it isn't called until after ItemProcessor4.

What is the correct way to share data between delegates in a compositeItemProcessor?

Is a solution of using util:map that is updated in itemProcessor1 and read in itemProcessor4 under the circumstances that the commit-interval is set to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the step execution context won't work as it is persisted at chunk boundary, so it can't be shared between processors within the same chunk.

`AfterProcess` is called after the registered item processor, which is the composite processor in your case (so after ItemProcessor4). This won't work neither.

The only option left is to use some data holder object that you share between item processors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks as per my edit i have went for a Map declared in the spring config for now. Unless you think there is a better means of storing the data?

Comment: I would do it that way too, with a bean of type map which is shared between processors.

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to state that there are two types of ExecutionContexts, one at step-level, one at job-level.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

You should be able to get the job context and set keys on that, from the step context

Comment: I have checked this page but it does not show how i access the stepExecutioner. If i add a '@BeforeStep' to one of the ItemProcessors it does not get called. And as mentioned above if i use '@AfterStep' or '@AfterProcess' they will not get called when they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in my application too. I went with creating a `data transfer object` `ItemProcessorDto` which will be shared by all the `ItemProcessors`. You can store data in this DTO object in first processor and all the remaining processors will get the information out of this DTO object. In addition to that any `ItemProcessor` could `update` or `retrieve` the data out of the DTO.

> Below is a code snippet:

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor1<ItemProcessorDto> itemProcessor1() {
    log.info("Generating ItemProcessor1");
    return new ItemProcessor1();
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor2<ItemProcessorDto> itemProcessor2() {
    log.info("Generating ItemProcessor2");
    return new ItemProcessor2();
}
@Bean
public ItemProcessor3<ItemProcessorDto> itemProcessor3() {
    log.info("Generating ItemProcessor3");
    return new ItemProcessor3();
}
@Bean
public ItemProcessor4<ItemProcessorDto> itemProcessor4() {
    log.info("Generating ItemProcessor4");
    return new ItemProcessor4();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public CompositeItemProcessor<ItemProcessorDto> compositeItemProcessor() {
    log.info("Generating CompositeItemProcessor");
    CompositeItemProcessor<ItemProcessorDto> compositeItemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
    compositeItemProcessor.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(itemProcessor1(), itemProcessor2(), itemProcessor3), itemProcessor4()));
    return compositeItemProcessor;
}

@Data
public class ItemProcessorDto {
    private List<String> sharedData_1;
    private Map<String, String> sharedData_2;
}
```