# How to share value between multiple ItemProcessor runs , in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have to set the line of a record in a `csv` file  within the record object  when processing it before passing it to the writer .
What i want to achieve is to declare a global variable lets say `line = 1` and each time an `itemProcessor`  runs it should assign its value to the current item , and increment its value by 1 `line++`.

How can i share a variable over multiple `itemProcessor` runs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch CompositeItemProcessor get value from other delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905582/spring-batch-compositeitemprocessor-get-value-from-other-delegates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `ExecutionContext` to save the `line` variable of either the `StepExecution` if you only need the `ExecutionContext` in the single `Step` or `JobExecution` if you need the `ExecutionContext` in other `Step`s of the `Job`.

Inject either execution in your `ItemProcessor`:

```
@Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution}") JobExecution jobExecution
```

or

```
@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution
```

Taking JobExecution as an example:

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public MyItemProcessor myItemProcessor(@Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution}") JobExecution jobExecution) {
    return new MyItemProcessor(jobExecution);
}

@Bean
public Step myStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
        ...
        .processor(myItemProcessor(null))
        ...
        .build()
}
```

```
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MyItem, MyItem> {

    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    public MyItemProcessor() {
        this.executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    }

    @Override
    public MyItem process(MyItem item) throws Exception {
        // get the line from previous item processors, if exists, otherwise start with 0
        int line = executionContext.getInt("myLineKey", 0);
        item.setLine(line++);
        // save the line for other item processors
        item.put("myLineKey", line);
        return item;
    }

}
```